Which form is more natural? early or earlier
I'm a English learner form Japan. I hope someone helps me out about "early or earlier".


You should have got up early.
You should have got up earlier.


Can we say both or not? Which sentence sounds more natural?

They both sound natural, but earlier is the comparative form so it means 'earlier than the time you did get up'.

Getting up early means getting up earlier than usual. If I wake up at 7:00 every day, then 6:00 is early, and 6:55 is also early, especially if I gave myself five extra minutes for a reason. For someone else, 6:00 might be late.
Earlier is just a regular comparative adjective, except in this context it's implicitly clear that the comparison is to the time I got up today.
If I arrive late because I slept too long, then factually I should have gotten up earlier than I did. But you don't know whether I got up early, on time, or late relative to my normal routine. "You should have gotten up early" is only appropriate if I got up at the usual time, and could be offensive otherwise—I did get up early, give me some credit!

How sweet of you!!!!  Thank you for your comment!

'Early' could just mean 'earlier than most people'. I always get up at 6 AM, and I think that is quite early.

@MichaelHarvey Interesting, I disagree.

early adjective, adverb near the beginning of (a period of time), or before the usual, expected, or planned time - Cambridge Dictionary.

@MichaelHarvey "Well sir, class only started five minutes ago, so I think if you check Cambridge Dictionary you'll find I'm actually early." Not every definition automatically applies in every case.

You wrote Getting up early means getting up earlier than usual; I assert that it can mean merely getting up early in the day.

I get up early everyday, 5:30 am.  Early has more than one definition.  It can mean earlier than expected or it can mean toward the beginning of a period (ex. the early morning).  Is early morning earlier than early morning?  Is that what you are implying?  Use your dictionary.

If either of you want to write your own answer, feel free. To me they're distinctly different senses.

@the-baby-is-you - According to the two major dictionaries I've checked, your answer is misleading at best.  If you write and publish your own dictionary, you won't have to say what things mean to you.  You can just say that's the definition of the word,  as others and I have.
